# powershell add-content contains ""

Tags: powershell

I have a question about the syntax in powershell for `Add-Content`. My problem is, I want to add text into a textfile and that this text contains `""` which is not working. For example:

`Add-Content -Value "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\"foobar.exe""`

Now the output should look like this:

```
c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\"foobar.exe"
```

and that does not work because of these `""`. 
Is there a way to get these `""` in the `-value` parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
Add-Content -Value "c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\`"foobar.exe`"" -Path .\AA.TXT
```

escaping the inner `""`

Or using single quote to enclose the double quote

```
Add-Content -Value 'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\"foobar.exe"' -Path .\AA.TXT
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind and fast help, I am trying to work with variables in there too. Like Start-Automating wrote, if I use single quotes in combination with double-quotes it ignores my variables. So I tried something like this: Add-Content -Value 'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\"foobar.exe" -i c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\'$title'' and either he ignores the variable or gives me an error message.

Comment: its still not working. Or maybe I did not understand your solution: `'"c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\"foobar.exe" -i "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\"'$title'"\"'$title'".txt"`. That is what I have tried and like I said it is still not working.

Comment: @sebastian Ask a new question I not understand what is `$title` and how you want to use it... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a few different tricks:

- Include the doubly quoted items within a singly quoted string.  This makes PowerShell ignore variables, too.  For instance:  'I Said "Something"'
- Include the doubly quoted items with a preceding backtick.  Backticks are the escape character in PowerShell, like \ in javascript or C, and this will make the " part of the string.
- Use a here document .  They start like this: @" and must end with a "@ at the start of a line.  This will still let you use variables within the quotes, and still let regular double quotes be.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you give me an example for cases 2 and 3 and maybe you know how it works that it does not ignore variables?